# Using a variable as jQuery class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know that this question was answered multiple times here on stackoverflow, but i just can't get it to work on my problem.

What i want to do is, when a `<label>` is clicked, check for the labels class and change all matching elements to `backgroundColor : #000000`

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('label').click(function(){
        var group = this.className ;
        $('label .'+group).css({
            'backgroundColor'   : '#000000'
        })  ;
    })  ;
});
```

Unfortunately, this just does nothing. It even throws no error. Where is my fault?

**Solution**

I had to remove the whitespace in the selector:

```
$('label.'+group)
```

Comment: What is your error? Also, please post the html.

Comment: What is the value of `group`?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the whitespace in  `$('label .'+group)`

Comment: It is possible that the `label` contains more than one class name, which could cause problems for your selector. We need more information.

Comment: group is the classname 'a_2'

Comment: The label has only one class and it it correctly submitted to group.
my error is, that the elements don't change the color. I'll try the whitespace thing

Comment: ...i have removed the whitespace and it worked. What the hell?
Thank you very much. @Rox, if you could change your comment into an answer, i would like to accept this :)

Comment: @Sprottenwels: The space means "descendant of".  http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/ `$('label.a_2')` means "labels with the class `a_2`", `$('label .a_2')` means "any element with the class `a_2` that's a descendant of a `label`".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you should remove the whitespace in `$('label .'+group)`.

`$('label .'+group)` means all the elements with the group class in all `<label>`, while `$('label.'+group)` means the all `<label>` with group class.